# Binary manipulate files Javascript

Tags: javascript, binary

I try to manipulate binary file, ex i want to change colour of simple bmp file.

Here is my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/51tLpwy8/

Here is bmp file to load https://ufile.io/sx9o5

And my code :

```
<body onload='
// Reset the textarea value
m.value="00";
// Init the top cell content
for(i=0;i<16;i++)
  t.innerHTML+=(0+i.toString(16)).slice(-2)+" ";
'>
<input onchange='
// When a file is selected, reset h
h="";
// Read the uploaded file as an ArrayBuffer
(f=new FileReader).readAsArrayBuffer(w.files[0]);
f.onload=function(){

  // Loop on the file bytes
  for(i in u=new Uint8Array(f.result))

    // Convert each byte in hexadecimal
    h+=(0+u[i].toString(16)).slice(-2);

console.log(h);
  // Write h in the hex textarea
  m.value=h;

  // Trigger oninput on hex textarea
  m.oninput()

}'
```

What i want - change ex. color of yellow to green, with a some function.
Thanks for help!

Comment: You need to either learn the BMP file format, or use some library. Show your effort please.

Comment: Urgh. Inline javascript is deprecated.

Comment: And please provide a [mcve]. That means: remove all the unneccessary stuff, just show the FileReader part. Also give a sample input/output

Comment: Any specific reason you are trying to do it with binary? Why not load the image as an RGB array then just edit the RGB values in the array then write a new image from RGB array (or save over old image)?